# how to send multiple html tablerow values into a PHP file

Tags: php

I'm new to the php environment and just need to know about from submission. Given below is my html table containing multiple rows.(This table is generated by PHP ECHO statements inside the server).

I need your help to submit these values (Actually I need only the SAMCODE and the SAMQTY fields to be submitted) into a PHP called SaveSample.php

I have tried with normal `post[txtCode]` format and `file_get_contents('php://input'))` format with `foreach Loop`

s to get them into arrays and expand. But not successful.

Please help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/body.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/table_sampleList.css"/>

<title>Sample Issue</title>

</head>

<body>

<div align="center">

<table width="234" border="1" id="sampleTable"  >
  <tr bgcolor="#0033FF" style="color:#FFF" height="38" >

    <th scope="col"  with="55">&nbsp;SAMCODE</th>
    <th scope="col" width="250" >&nbsp;SAMNAME</th>
    <th scope="col" width="75" >&nbsp;SAMSIZE</th>
    <th scope="col" width="75">&nbsp;INSTOCK</th>
    <th scope="col" width="20px">&nbsp;SAMQTY</th>    
  </tr>





<tbody id='sampBody'>
<TR bgcolor='#8CC6FF'><td><input name='txtCode[]' type='text' value='SA0033'size='5'  /></td><td>Kool n fresh</td><td>100ml</td><td>100</td><td><input name='txtQty[]' type='text' value='3' maxlength='2' size='3'  /></td></tr>

<TR bgcolor='#F0F9FB'><td><input name='txtCode[]' type='text' value='SA0038'size='5'  /></td><td>Amoxip</td><td>8s</td>
  <td>8</td><td><input name='txtQty[]' type='text' value='5' maxlength='2' size='3'  /></td></tr>

<TR bgcolor='#8CC6FF'><td><input name='txtCode[]' type='text' value='SA0976'size='5'  /></td><td>Umetac</td><td>10x10</td>
  <td>89</td><td><input name='txtQty[]' type='text' value='11' maxlength='2' size='3'  /></td></tr>

<TR bgcolor='#F0F9FB'><td><input name='txtCode[]' type='text' value='SA0966'size='5'  /></td><td>Umexim 200mg</td><td>10x1</td>
  <td>25</td><td><input name='txtQty[]' type='text' value='4' maxlength='2' size='3'  /></td></tr>


</tbody> 

</table>


 </div>



<form name='formSampList' method='post'  action='saveSamp.php' onsubmit=''  >

  <input name='Send' type='submit' value='Submit' />
  <input name='Cancel' type='reset' value='Cancel' onclick='' />
</form>

</body>
```

Comment: The "normal" `post[txtCode]` would normally be `$_POST['txtCode']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table isn't included inside the form tags, so it won't be submitted. Otherwise it looks fine to me, you should be able to process it as an array in the `$_POST['txtCode']` variable

Comment: Nice one boss..TnQ ..now I get the data

Answer (score 0):

for input type type 'text' i will encourage you to remove these [] from name attributes, you will need it only for input type 'checkbox'

Nown if you want to get values from input 'txtCode', in PHP you should do this:

```
$_POST['txtCode']
```

attention : case is sensitive for array keys in PHP
Trick : if you do not want to know if data was sent by POST or GET, you can use $_REQUEST['YOUR_KEY'] in PHP Code

Best Regards,
Anis

Comment: If you remove square brackets, you will have single scalar variable, not an array in post.